# Python tinydb - How to get specific element name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tinydb

This is what my structure looks like:

```
{'MovieName': 'Its-a-Wonderful-Life', 'Description': 'MovieDiscription', 'IMDBID': '0038650'}
```

I want to print out only the MovieName element.

I'm using this code to get it:

```
db = TinyDB('Databases/Downloaded_Movies.json')

for item in db:

   print(item.MovieName)
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
 AttributeError: 'Document' object has no attribute 'MovieName'
```

How do I fix the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TinyDB expects an indexed table document, not a list. Unless you want to write a custom middleware for your TinyDB, you'll either have to modify your JSON

```
"1 ": {'MovieName': 'Its-a-Wonderful-Life', 'Description': 'MovieDiscription', 'IMDBID': '0038650'}
```

or you can try to print the element with indexes as

```
import json
wjson = db.read()    
wjdata = json.loads(wjson)
print wjdata['1'][0]['Moviename']
```